# How can be convert object arrays into multidimensional arrays in node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

We have a object arrays the below format in node.js and we want to this array in multidimensional arrays.

object arrays :

```
[ { id: 4,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 1,
    attribute_id: 6,
    attribute_label: 'level4',
    attribute_order: 1,
    attribute_name: 'level4_1'
  { id: 4,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 1,
    attribute_id: 7,
    attribute_label: 'level5',
    attribute_order: 2,
    attribute_name: 'level5_1'
  { id: 15,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 2,
    attribute_id: null,
    attribute_label: null,
    attribute_order: null,
    attribute_name: null },
  { id: 5,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 3,
    attribute_id: 8,
    attribute_label: 'level6',
    attribute_order: 1,
    attribute_name: 'level6_1'
  { id: 5,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 3,
    attribute_id: 9,
    attribute_label: 'level7',
    attribute_order: 2,
    attribute_name: 'level7_1'
  { id: 6,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 4,
    attribute_id: 10,
    attribute_label: 'level8',
    attribute_order: 1,
    attribute_name: 'level8_1'
  { id: 14,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 5,
    attribute_id: null,
    attribute_label: null,
    attribute_order: null,
    attribute_name: null } ]
```

and we want to this object array in below format (multidimensional arrays). please suggest that how can we convert it the below formate

```
[ [ { id: 4,
      process_id: 94,
      process_type: 'Section',
      process_type_order: 1,
      attribute_id: 6,
      attribute_label: 'level4',
      attribute_order: 1,
      attribute_name: 'level4_1' },
    { id: 4,
      process_id: 94,
      process_type: 'Section',
      process_type_order: 1,
      attribute_id: 7,
      attribute_label: 'level5',
      attribute_order: 2,
      attribute_name: 'level5_1' } ],

   [ { id: 15,
      process_id: 94,
      process_type: 'Section',
      process_type_order: 2,
      attribute_id: null,
      attribute_label: null,
      attribute_order: null,
      attribute_name: null } ],

  [ { id: 5,
      process_id: 94,
      process_type: 'Section',
      process_type_order: 3,
      attribute_id: 8,
      attribute_label: 'level6',
      attribute_order: 1,
      attribute_name: 'level6_1' },
    { id: 5,
      process_id: 94,
      process_type: 'Section',
      process_type_order: 3,
      attribute_id: 9,
      attribute_label: 'level7',
      attribute_order: 2,
      attribute_name: 'level7_1' } ],
  [ { id: 6,
      process_id: 94,
      process_type: 'Section',
      process_type_order: 4,
      attribute_id: 10,
      attribute_label: 'level8',
      attribute_order: 1,
      attribute_name: 'level8_1' } ],
  [ { id: 14,
      process_id: 94,
      process_type: 'Section',
      process_type_order: 5,
      attribute_id: null,
      attribute_label: null,
      attribute_order: null,
      attribute_name: null } ],
  ]
```

Comment: we need to use this multidimensional  array in page listing.

Comment: And? You've not put any effort into trying to solve this it seems. Where is your attempt? SO isn't a free development service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+array+group

Comment: hey Andy thanks for your suggestion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps createMultiArray creates your desired Array based on your objects id's:

```
var array = [ { id: 4,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 1,
    attribute_id: 6,
    attribute_label: 'level4',
    attribute_order: 1,
    attribute_name: 'level4_1'
              },
  { id: 4,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 1,
    attribute_id: 7,
    attribute_label: 'level5',
    attribute_order: 2,
    attribute_name: 'level5_1'
              },
  { id: 15,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 2,
    attribute_id: null,
    attribute_label: null,
    attribute_order: null,
    attribute_name: null },
  { id: 5,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 3,
    attribute_id: 8,
    attribute_label: 'level6',
    attribute_order: 1,
    attribute_name: 'level6_1',
  },
  { id: 5,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 3,
    attribute_id: 9,
    attribute_label: 'level7',
    attribute_order: 2,
    attribute_name: 'level7_1'
  },
  { id: 6,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 4,
    attribute_id: 10,
    attribute_label: 'level8',
    attribute_order: 1,
    attribute_name: 'level8_1'
  },
  { id: 14,
    process_id: 94,
    process_type: 'Section',
    process_type_order: 5,
    attribute_id: null,
    attribute_label: null,
    attribute_order: null,
    attribute_name: null } ]


function createMultiArray(array){
  var newArray = [];
  array.forEach(function(obj,index){
    var subarray;
    var subArrayExists = false;
    for(var sub=0; sub < newArray.length; sub++){
      subarray = newArray[sub];
      if(subarray.some(function(subobj){ 
        return subobj.id == obj.id;
      })){
         subArrayExists = true;
         break;
      }
    }

    if(!subArrayExists){
      newArray.push([obj]);
    }
    else{
      subarray.push(obj);
    }

  });
  return newArray;
}


createMultiArray(array);
```